# Give Suggestions to Get Data from Collections using Meteor?

Tags: meteor

How to get data from Collections using Meteor JS?

- Initially created one collection then inserted data by manually certain records contains username, email, password.
- In this collection allows **duplicates** also.
- Basically my query is **how to get one record based on username?** and I am tries also get data successfully but i didn't know i followed correct way or not.
- When ever inserted data to collections it give one id.I am not using this ID even fetch or update times also. So **What is the use of this ID?**
- If collections contains **Duplicate Usernames** so in this situation How to get data?

Please see the below insert query & fetch data and give me suggestions about my queries?.

Thank you.

JS Code :

Insert Query:

```
Players.insert({email: email, password : password,username : username }
          , function( error, result) 
          { 
            if ( error ) console.log ( error ); //info about what went wrong
            if ( result ) //the result is id so what is use of this id?
            {
             console.log ( "result="+result );//the _id of new object if successful
             alert("Sucessfully Created");

             }          
           });
```

Fetch Data:

```
    //here get the data based on username so this is correct way or not.
    var PDetails =  Players.findOne({username: 'venkat'});
    console.log("PDetails="+PDetails.email);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should *absolutely not* create your own, insecure authentication system like this. Meteor has a built in [Accounts API](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_api) that is very secure. It's simple to use once you have read the documentation. It does not allow duplicate usernames or email addresses, but you can use a `user` object's `profile` field to add something like a duplicable `playerName` or `characterName` property.

Collection inserts return the newly generated `_id` field of the document you just inserted, so that you can immediately work with that new document by `_id`. One reason this is useful is that on the client side, Meteor only allows you to update documents one at a time by matching against their `_id` field.

Comment: yeah,But some times to handle own collections at that time what i can do for this problem?.@Cuberto

Comment: And I am not using registration & login phases. I need to handle information about users.Initially show user name list and click any user name then get information about that user.In this way which one is best or is there any best resource for understanding this?.@Cuberto

Comment: The `Accounts` package adds a `users` collection which has all the user records. You'll want to add your seed records from a server method using the `Accounts.createUser` function. Then you can retrieve the records using `Meteor.users.find()`. Once you disable the `autopublish` package, you'll need to manually publish the user fields to the clients, or otherwise return the user documents from a server method. This is all explained in the [documentation](http://docs.meteor.com/#accounts_api).

Comment: yeah,But some times use more than one collection so in this time what i can do?.@Cuberto

Comment: If you have a generic collection where you are retrieving single documents based on a non-unique field, you will need to fall back to some second field to get the actual document you want. For example, `Meteor.users.find({"profile.playerName": "Venkat"}).count()` would tell you how many documents in the `users` collection have a `profile.playerName` field with value `"Venkat"`. I believe this is what you're asking about.

Comment: No,More than one collection means one for players profile collection and another for assume players game description collections so in this time how to use accounts package for both?.@Cuberto.

Comment: Just like you would specify any other kind of relationship in MongoDB. You just add a `userId` field on your secondary collections that point to the owning document in the `users` collection. So, for example, if you have a `characters` collection, a character object might look like: `{_id: "...", userId: "...", name: "Gandalf", health: 74}`.

Comment: okay i understand everything fine,but the final problem is how to get `_id` based on username is it possible or is there any another solution  for this?@Cuberto

Comment: `Meteor.users.findOne({username: "Venkat"})._id;`

Comment: When user created collections use? ex                           Players = new Meteor.Collection("players");?.@Cuberto.